# ERROR: No such API key. Please add it to your configuration (done automatically on initial `gem push`). How to solve this issue?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I want to push a gem on Rubygems. But I always get this message:

```
C:\ruby\my_gem>gem push my_gem-0.0.1.gem -k rubygems_api_key
Pushing gem to https://rubygems.org...
ERROR:  No such API key. Please add it to your configuration (done automatically on initial `gem push`).
```

I have the key set in `C:\Documents and Settings\User\.gem\credentials`

```
---
rubygems_api_key: e06b38 ...
:rubygems_api_key: e06b38 ...
```

I copy/paste it from my Rubygems' profile page. So it it correct. But I get an error.
What is the problem? How to solve it?

Answer (score 6):

For some reason rubygems removes the `api_key` part from the `rubygems_api_key` key. But you can add any other key to the credentials file and use it referencing it by its complete name.

https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/4305567f0182bc08e27c63dcc99842a094af38c6/lib/rubygems/config_file.rb#L289-L293

If you have the following in the `.gem/credentials`

```
---
:rubygems_api_key: e06b38 ...
:someother_api_key: 43240230...
:secret: 08n23u30...
```

You should be able to run

```
gem push my_gem-0.0.1.gem -k rubygems
# this is the same as not using the -k/--key arg
gem push my_gem-0.0.1.gem
```

or

```
gem push my_gem-0.0.1.gem -k someother_api_key
gem push my_gem-0.0.1.gem -k secret
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the second line in your credentials file is incorrect.  In my file, the first line is three dashes, and the second line starts with a colon.  So I think it should be:

```
---
:rubygems_api_key: e06b38 ...
```

If you go to your profile page on rubygems.org, you'll find a `curl` command that you can cut-and-paste to your command line that will create this file for you.

Comment: Do I need to install `curl`? I'm on Windows.

Comment: No, cut and paste should be fine.  Just delete your second line.  I'm on windows also.  I just assumed Linux, since most of the world is :-)

Comment: @Green: did you find the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The key name should be prefixed with a colon. When Ruby imports a yaml file, keys without a colon before them are interpreted as strings; keys prefixed with a colon are interpreted as symbols. The following example:

```
{"string_key" => "value 1", :symbol_key => "value 2"}.to_yaml
```

Outputs this:

```
---
string_key: value 1
:symbol_key: value 2
```